# Exporting sql query in access to text

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently export the data from a passthrough query to a text using VBA in access and I would like to add to the VBA.  Once it exports the data I would then like it to export the actual sql query to a seperate text.  Does anyone know how to add this?

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with? Getting the SQL? Creating a text file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileSystemObject. The example below uses late binding, but you can set a reference to the Windows Script Host and use the commented types.

```
Dim fs As Object ''FileSystemObject
Dim tsOut As Object ''TextStream

sFileOut = "z:\docs\FileOut.txt"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tsOut = fs.OpenTextFile(sFileOut, 8) ''ForAppending
''Or
'' Set tsOut = fs.CreateTextFile(sFileOut, True) ''Overwrite

sSQL = CurrentDB.QueryDefs(qry).SQL

tsOut.WriteLine sSQL

tsOut.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exporting string to a text file figured out, you can get the SQL text of a query from:

```
Dim strSQL as string
strSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Your query name here").SQL
```